# How to prevent additional distros from installing their own GRUB boot loader

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, boot-order

I recently installed Kubuntu 15.10 on top of a dual-boot with Ubuntu Studio 15.10 and Windows 10. Yesterday I removed the Kubuntu, as I felt it wasn't stable enough.

As I had suspected, the Kubuntu, when installed at the time, replaced the GRUB in Ubuntu with it's own, although it found the other OSes after sudo update-grub.

When I deleted the partition containing the Kubuntu 15.10, it's GRUB went with it, and I had to boot into grub rescue mode, which was actually fairly straightforward, using [these instructions.](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/776643-how-to-rescue-a-non-booting-grub-2-on-linux/)

Is there a way to prevent a new Ubuntu, or any new Linux for that matter, from replacing the existing GRUB with it's own, and appointing itself as the first OS?

I'd prefer to keep the existing GRUB, and run sudo update-grub in the Ubuntu Studio - which I want to be my number one distro - to find any recently installed distros, and add them to the boot order.

I searched other answers, but didn't find any clear instructions on how to do this. If I missed something, I'd be glad to know, and would happily remove this question, if it turns out to be a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not being a multi-distro user for a number of years and,  if I remember correctly.

What happens is that the 2nd distro (and later ones) only ADDS information to the existing GRUB file and does not replace the file itself.

Again,  IF,  I repeat IF,  I remember correctly,  GRUB assums that the last distro knstalled is the primary version and places it in the first position for booting unattended.

While GRUB can be edited,  I found it simpler to press the boot menu key while startingvand selectingvthe OS that I wanted from the boot menu when it appeared.

Comment: So the GRUB remains in /dev/sda, and the solution would be removing the (head) entry for the distro due to be uninstalled, from the GRUB? Then move the older OS to the top? The only problem is, I have a hard time finding the references to individual boot menu items, all I find in the GRUB files, is a myriad of if statements.

Comment: He is correct. @theodorn install `grub-optimizer` and you will have all the options neatly lined up in a GUI.

Comment: Yes, I briefly tested `grub-customizer`, it is easy to use. One more question, if in a three OS system, I remove the reference to the last installed OS in `grub-customizer`, move Ubuntu Studio to the top, do `sudo update-grub`, and finally `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`, will I have a bootable GRUB, with Ubuntu Studio on top? Because, the last step I took in GRUB RESCUE, was to `grub-install` after I was back in Ubuntu Studio. It worked to restore the GRUB menu.